# How to follow page redirects using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, python-requests-html

I have this simple code:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://yahoo.com')
print(r.url)
```

Which after executing, prints:

```
https://uk.yahoo.com/?p=us
```

I want to see:

1. How many redirects have happened before arriving on `https://uk.yahoo.com/?p=us` (clearly, there is redirect as I typed `https://yahoo.com` originally)?
2. I also want to save the content of each page, not only the last one. How to do this?

Comment: You want `requests` to *not* automatically follow the redirects, so you can see each page in the chain. Then you can keep manually following them until you get to the final result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `response.history`. From the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history)...

> The Response.history list contains the Response objects that were
>   created in order to complete the request. The list is sorted from the
>   oldest to the most recent response.

So, to get the number of intermediate URLs, you could do something like:

```
response = requests.get(url)
print(len(response.history))
```

And to get what those URLs actually were and what their responses contain, you could do:

```
for resp in response.history:
    print(resp.url, resp.text)
```

If needed, you can also submit a new request to the intermediate URLs with the optional parameter `allow_redirects` set to `False`:

`r = requests.get(resp.url, allow_redirects=False)`

Comment: Note that you'd have to not follow the redirects when making the intermediate URL requests.

Comment: @AndroidNoobie Why is it necessary to use urlib? isn't there a way to get the content (I mean the page content) using requests?

Comment: Yes, `r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)`. I'll update my answer, even though this is marked as a duplicate.

Comment: To get the intermiediate pages content, Instead of `r = requests.get(resp.url, allow_redirects=False)` for each history item `resp`, can't I use `resp.text` as each history item is already a response object?

Comment: I think no need to submit new request for each history item. They are already response object. Just extract the data from them. So your answer should be `for resp in response.history` you d=just do `print(resp.text)`. No need to do new get.request per url. Plz update the answer or correct me.

Comment: Answer updated.